# the unexpected behavior of smart match operator in perl

Tags: perl

according to perlop:[Smartmatch-Operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator),the following code:

```
use 5.012;

my @array = qw/1 2/;

print @array ~~ 2
    ? "true"
    : "false";
```

should use the rule

> Left      Right      Description and pseudocode
>    ===============================================================
>
> Any       Num        numeric equality(like: Any == Num)

but the output is "false".but I think

```
@array == 2
```

should be true.Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I'm unsure about this question, but maybe this helps: the code compiles to a smart match with an array **ref**:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e '@a = (1, 2); print @a ~~ 2'
@a = (1, 2);
print \@a ~~ 2;
-e syntax OK
```

So you're actually checking for referential equality, which should be false in most cases. ;) However, checking for an array's length is maybe too easy for the smart match operator since it can be done with `==`:

```
$ perl -le '@a = (42, 17); print @a == 2'
1
```

I would prefer this method because it's more obvious to Perl programmers what you're testing for.

Note that smart match isn't symmetrical. Reversing the order performs an grep search on that array:

```
$ perl -nle '@a = (42, 17); print $_ ~~ @a ? "ok" : "no"'
1
no
2
no
17
ok
```

Comment: perl -MO=Deparse -e '@a = (1, 2); print 2~~@a'; #=>print 2 ~~ \@a;.even if right operand is an array,it's still shown as an reference.